# Loop selection of data subsets across a series of columns to generate new variables

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I am trying to find the optimal way to generate a series of 1/0 coded columns depending on whether specific values occur during a character string which contains multiple values.

I have a data column (skin_problems) that contains between 1 to n values stored as characters

```
"1"
"6"
"6 12"
```

The values range from 1 to n (i.e if the maximum value is 10 then its also possible for the column to contain "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10"

These are outputs from data collection where the user has a select_multiple type option; i.e they have a list of options and tick all that apply.
So if they select 1 the column contains just `"1"`, if they select 6 & 12 the column contains `"6 12"`

I'm trying to then generate some new variables based on the values in this column. i.e essentially to generate 1/0 values based on what the user selected.

For example if any of the entries is 3 then new var3 = 1
So

```
"1"
"2 3"
"3"
"12 13"
"4 3"
```

In this example the 2nd, 3rd, 5th rows would all be correct and for those rows the value of newvar3 should be set to 1.

I thought the easiest way was to start by using separate

```
cases_per_house <- separate(cases_per_house,into = c("p1","p2","p3","p4","p5","p6","p7","p8","p9","p10","p11","p12","p13"),skin_problem,sep=" ")
```

> I know the maximum number of values is 13, so I separate the column skin_problem into a maximum of 13 separate columns. I can then look at each column and apply a logical to the value contained in that column

Then I thought I should be able to do:

```
cases_per_house$ulcer[cases_per_house$p1==1] <-1
```

> If the value of p1 is 1 then set the value of ulcer ulcer to be 1

That works and I can repeat for the different values that might be in variable p1.

i.e

```
cases_per_house$lump[cases_per_house$p1==2] <-1
```

> If the value of p1 is 2 then set the value of lump to be 1

What I'd like to be able to do is repeat that looping through p1>p13
i.e

```
ulcer = 1 if p1 = 1 
lump = 1 if p1 = 2
ulcer = 1 if p2 = 1
lump = 1 if p2 = 2
```

I've tried approaches using apply and for loops with little joy.
Initially I also tried using grep on the original column without using separate but couldn't get that to work as its pretty difficult to come up with a regular expression given the numbers in the column can vary in order and the number of them.

Hope this is clear - please let me know if anything I can do clarify/improve the question

Comment: Just to add ideally either a tidyverse or base R approach as those are tool suites I am most familar with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the value matching function to your separated data, with 1 for a match and 0 if not, then append the column to the original dataframe, as in the following:

```
text<-data.frame(sel=c("1","6","6 12","1","2 3","3","12 13","4 3"))
library(tidyr)
text<-separate(text, 1, c("p1","p2","p3","p4","p5","p6","p7","p8","p9","p10","p11","p12","p13"))

for(i in 1:13){
sel<-as.data.frame(apply(text, 1, function(x) as.integer(i %in% x)))
names(sel) <- paste0("sel", i)
text <- cbind(text,sel)
}
```